# How to do test statistic on difference in two independent variables?

Tags: econometrics

If i have time series regression $R_{i,t} = \alpha + \beta x_1 + \gamma x_2 + \delta x_3 + \varepsilon_i$

In this case, how can I conduct test statistic of $\beta - \gamma$? Is it to use unpaired two sample?

(http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/t-test-formula)

Comment: depends on your sample and what kind of data set you use.

Comment: Your notation is unclear: the explained variable depend upon $i,t$ while the explanatory variables have no subscript and the random term depends upon $i$ only. There are three equivalent ways to do your test: Wald, Fisher and Lagrange.